# Как решить проблему UndefinedMetricWarning при использовании GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn, классификация

Для выбора лучших параметров модели использую GridSearchCV. Лучшие параметры модели хочу выбрать по метрике f1. Так же в процессе обучения хочу отслеживать метрики precision и recall.

Для этого делаю:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer

param_grid = {
    'num_leaves':[5,15,45],
    'learning_rate': [0.005, 0.01, 0.1],
    'n_estimators': [100,200,300]
}

scoring = {
    'accuracy': make_scorer(accuracy_score),
    'precision': make_scorer(precision_score),
    'recall': make_scorer(recall_score),
    'f1': make_scorer(f1_score),    
}

grid = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid = param_grid, cv = 4, verbose = 5, scoring = scoring, refit = 'f1')

grid.fit(X_train_t, y_train_t)
```

При обучении получаю `UndefinedMetricWarning` и все дальнейшие значения `precision`, `recall` и `f1` ровняются 0:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1143: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1143: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
[CV]  learning_rate=0.005, n_estimators=100, num_leaves=5, accuracy=0.5469064074675771, precision=0.0, recall=0.0, f1=0.0, total=   5.4s
```

Как видите, sklearn почему-то не обнаружил заданных метрик (`UndefinedMetricWarning`) и в дальнейшем процессе обучения, они у нас ровняются 0. Делал вроде все так, как в документации описано. 
Как сделать так, чтобы указанные метрики отслеживались и `grid.best_estimator_` выбирался по нужной мне метрике?

Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Данное предупреждение обычно говорит о том, что в предсказанных значениях `Y_pred` отсутствуют некоторые классы из `Y_test`.

Например, в `Y_test` есть классы: `{0, 1, 2, 3}`, а в `Y_pred`: `{0, 1, 2}`.
В этом случае некоторые метрики не могут быть правильно рассчитаны.